# How to prevent overlay of TreeSelect Checkbox auto collapse when click child node

Tags: angular, checkbox, tree, overlay, primeng

In the website document of primeNg https://primeng.org/treeselect#checkbox

First I click Documents checkbox -> Home checkbox
[When I click Document -> Home](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1flS.png)

Second I click Invoices checkbox

Result : The overlay auto collapse. That is a big error of prime but I don't find resolve for it

I very tryhard research document but I dont find resolve or hope for it :))

Answer (score 1):

That should be a bug in primeng. The action causes to hide overlay is unchecking a checkbox. However I found a workaround to achieve this problem. [You can find example code in StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nptqnd)

Comment: But the header dropdown checkbox can't work when I click it. Anyway your solution very awesome for me. Have a good day - many thanks

Comment: You are welcome! For other users who can face with same issue, it would be better if you can upvote and select this answer as an answer. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Here's my monkey patch of onClick() that allows me to close the overlay by clicking on the dropdown box.

```
  @ViewChild(TreeSelect)
  treeselect: TreeSelect;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.treeselect.onClick = this.monkeyPatchTreeSelectOnClick.bind(this);
  }

private monkeyPatchTreeSelectOnClick(event: any) {
  if (this.treeselect.disabled) {
    return;
  }

  if (
    !this.treeselect.overlayViewChild?.el?.nativeElement?.contains(event.target) &&
    !DomHandler.hasClass(event.target, 'p-treeselect-close') &&
    this.indicatesDropDownBox(event) // This is the line added for the fix
  ) {
    if (this.treeselect.overlayVisible) {
      this.treeselect.hide();
    } else {
      this.treeselect.show();
    }

    this.treeselect.focusInput?.nativeElement.focus();
  }
}

private indicatesDropDownBox(event: any) {
  const classesIndicatingDropdownWasClicked = [
    'p-treeselect-label',
    'p-treeselect-label-container',
    'p-treeselect-trigger',
    'p-treeselect-trigger-icon',
  ];
  const indicatesDropDownBox = classesIndicatingDropdownWasClicked.some((c) => DomHandler.hasClass(event.target, c));
  return indicatesDropDownBox;
}
```

This is the PrimeNg bug: [TreeSelect popup closes when unchecking nodes #13698](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/13698)